# Overvoltage on input pin of analog switch

Tags: integrated-circuit, analog-switch

I'm building a device, where I need to switch pin between analog signal 0 V-5 V and 12 V digital signal. I was thinking I could use a BL1551 ([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811021622_BL-Shanghai-Belling-BL1551_C82528.pdf)) or similar analog switch to shut off the analog signal source when I want to apply the 12 V signal. Input pin of the analog switch would be exposed to 12 V (which is significantly above its VCC), but it would be in its off state. The datasheet states that it can only switch voltages up to VCC but nothing about voltages in its OFF state.

Would that damage the switch or cause voltage or current leakage to the analog signal source? I'm also worried about the ESD protection circuitry clipping the voltage on the input pin to VCC.

Comment: If you have a 12V supply (or +/-12V) there are analog switches that will do this. They typically take +/-12V and may need 5V for the logic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will damage the device, and just about any other analog switch that is not powered with VCC = 12 V. From the datasheet, this device has a VCC abs max of 6 V, and no other pin can go above VCC + 0.3 V (the 0.3 V would be the voltage drop of the ESD protection diode when it is on):

[image]

Exceeding the abs max will very likely damage the device permanently, as indicated in Note (2) in the datasheet.

Either use an analog switch powered with VCC = 12 V (you'd need to choose a different one, of course), or consider a relay. The relay can be mechanical, or you can use solid state relay (SSR) if you need it to be smaller and consume less power (but SSRs are generally more expensive).

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet absolute maximum ratings table lists the DC switch voltage as -0.3 V - (Vsup + 0.3) V, regardless of operating condition. The chip is not qualified or designed to operate in the condition that you propose, even when the switch is OFF.

Your guess about ESD protection circuitry is probably a correct one - applying 12 V to the pin will cause the pin to conduct current in an attempt to clip the voltage, which could lead to chip damage.